# Add site to Table of Contents title without showing in Header

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to have the term site above the table of contents next to the title Table of Contents.

I had the command

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{table of contents \hfill site}
```

used and i got this:

[image]

But here the problem is that the name is subsequently displayed in the header and there I would like to have only Table of Contents:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It will greatly help if you make this a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497).  The header and table of contents depend on many things, and your code will eliminate much confusion.

Comment: What is the word "site" supposed to mean in the present context? You use this word both in the title and in the first paragraph of your posting. Is "site" maybe an attempt to translate the German word "Seite"?

Comment: It's absolulely essential that you tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: I am using scrreprt with fancyhdr

Comment: And yes Seite = Site. It is a german document

Answer (score 1):

One way to reproduce your result is to have the same page style defined for both `plain` and `fancy`. (Or  applying `\thispagestyle{fancy}` to the `\tableofcontents`)

The following example  shows how to define `plain` explicitly (not different from the default), to be applied to the starting page of chapters and the ToC, and `fancy` to be applied elsewhere.

Guessing that you are using `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`   the way to change the table of contents title is through

```
\renewcaptionname{<language>}{\contentsname}{<new title for ToC>}
```

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis\hfill \normalfont\normalsize  Seite}   % added <<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% applied to chapter starting pages and ToC
\fancyhf{}% 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}%
}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{% applied to  pages 
\fancyhf{}% 
\lhead{\rightmark}%
\rhead{\thepage}%
}%

\pagestyle{fancy}% use this style

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents    
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```